# AWS GuardDuty: Why are we getting, probably false, PortProbeUnprotectedPort findings

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am testing GuardDuty on our AWS account and have some questions...

Every EC2 instance we manage, has a single "Recon:EC2/PortProbeUnprotectedPort" finding. Each for different port:

- EC2 instance 1: 1433
- EC2 instance 2: 433
- EC2 instance 3: 9000
- EC2 instance 4: 554
- EC2 instance 5: 110

All instances are on Debian, nmap scan for instance 5:

```
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp   open     ftp
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
443/tcp  open     https
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
8086/tcp open     d-s-n
8088/tcp open     radan-http
```

Netstat output on the instance:

```
# netstat -tpln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31962/proftpd: (acc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4949          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      589/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1106/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5389/grafana-server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      687/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2777/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2777/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2777/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9003          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2777/php-fpm.conf)
tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                    LISTEN      2736/influxd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1106/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      2736/influxd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2883/apache2
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7080          :::*                    LISTEN      12370/java
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2883/apache2
```

There is no sign of port 110 being open.

Any reasonable explanation of the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port is not open on the machine, but it is open on the Security Group that is protecting the machine. GuardDuty sees a problem in that a port is open in the Security Groups, but is not actually listening.

(This is just a guess, I have never experienced that message myself, hope this helps, please update if I am correct!).

Comment: The documentation states: This finding informs you that a port on an EC2 instance in your AWS environment is not blocked by a security group, access control list (ACL), or an on-host firewall (for example, Linux IPChains), and known scanners on the internet are actively probing it.

So it should catch if iptables are blocking it, but it is true that Security group is allowing all inbound traffic. Any other ideas, maybe you are even right and it is not well documented... Anybody else with some more insight?

Comment: There is nothing obviously inconsistent, here, @b4d, so it sounds like you are misinterpreting the meaning.  The fact that nothing is listening does not falsify the assertion that the port is being probed and is not blocked.  By allowing traffic to the port in the security group and the host firewall (if present) when it is not needed, you're creating a latent vulnerability to potentially be exploited later. Test: `telnet the.host.ip 110` → `Connection refused` means the connection attempt was seen by the host and actively rejected, meaning that end-to-end, it is unfiltered.

Comment: I have the same issue but on an eks node. The eks endpoints are private only, the eks nodes have private ip's only, the nlb only have 443 and 80 opened to eks but I still receive the "Unprotected port on EC2 instance xxxx is being probed." because I have the port 32001 opened to everyone on security group. I cannot understand how this can be possible since the eks node is not accessible from outside.